# Does a rule exist that directly governs inappropriately sized arrows used with bows?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, equipment

I'm wondering if it is legal to use inappropriately sized arrows for your bow.

So, does a rule exist that states whether or not a character can fire a Large arrow from a Medium bow, and simply suffer from oversize weapon penalties? (Which would nicely restrict arrow use to a singular size category difference in most cases.)
(^ Note that this is simply my expectation of what the rule would boil down to.)

Comment: Worth noting that, realistically, you can use a too-long arrow, but a too-short one will prevent a full draw.

Comment: Should this have the RAW tag, or are you willing to entertain house rule suggestions?  The fact that you suggest a potential rule while asking if any exist makes this unclear, IMO.  (Unless you literally want a yes/no answer to whether this specific rule exists.)

Comment: Arrows that are too short force you to take wimpy half-drawn shots. Arrows that are too long mess your accuracy up. Also, arrows of inadequate girth do quite often break into splinters on release from all the tension.

Comment: @Steve-O, I'm looking for a more general pointer to something concrete other than player experience. I will edit the question to allow for more clarification.

Comment: @eimyr arrows that are too long and mess up your shot is almost exactly what I was imagining in this situation. And "arrows of inadequate girth" implies too small, not too large, which feeds into an idea of this I already had, and that Zeiss Ikon also touched upon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Ammunition are weapons

If you read closely on the equipment chapter, you will notice that ammunition are weapons just like every other weapon, they simply have different rules governing how they should be used. Here, it says they are used with projectile weapons, so you cannot use ammunition without a projectile weapons (exceptions exists: see [throwing arrows](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/ammunition/arrow-throwing/)).

Every ammunition also has an entry on their weapon table for small and medium creatures separatedly. Those without an entry, use the damage from the ranged weapon or a special rule described on the ammunition's description.

This means that all rules governing weapons (sans exceptions) can be applied to ammunitions aswell, including the rule for [Inappropriatedly Sized Weapons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons#TOC-Weapon-Size):

> A weapon’s size category isn’t the same as its size as an object. Instead, a weapon’s size category is keyed to the size of the intended wielder. In general, a light weapon is an object two size categories smaller than the wielder, a one-handed weapon is an object one size category smaller than the wielder, and a two-handed weapon is an object of the same size category as the wielder.
>
> **Inappropriately Sized Weapons**: A creature can’t make optimum use of a weapon that isn’t properly sized for it. **A cumulative –2 penalty applies on attack rolls for each size category of difference between the size of its intended wielder and the size of its actual wielder**. If the creature isn’t proficient with the weapon, a –4 nonproficiency penalty also applies.

To give a few examples:

- A medium character wielding a medium-sized longbow with small-sized arrows would suffer a -2 penalty on his checks.
- A medium character wielding a small-sized longbow with small-sized arrows would suffer only a -4 penalty, as the weapon is innapropriate for his size, and the ammunition being used are innapropriate for his size aswell

Comment: How would this interact with the Handed-ness increase due to inappropriate size category of the arrow?
Characters are usually limited to what they can wield by this, so that you can't simply use a Colossal Greatsword with less accuracy.

Comment: Ammunition are normally not wielded. So there is no rule for that. Regardless, characters are limited to one size category away from their own. A large sized dagger does not become a two-handed weapon, but a 1h weapon. So ammunition (which are the size of a dagger or smaller), shouldnt become 2h either.

Comment: Ah, here we go: *" In general, a light weapon is an object two size categories smaller than the wielder, a one-handed weapon is an object one size category smaller than the wielder, and a two-handed weapon is an object of the same size category as the wielder."*

Comment: As for becoming smaller, there is no extra penalty for wielding small or even tiny-sized daggers, they still require one hand to use.

Comment: So the use of inappropriately sized arrows would be subjected to a limited size category increase of ... two? Up to a "two-handed" weapon, and Huge from Medium?

Comment: You mean a Huge arrow? You simply cannot use it, it is two-size categories larger.

Comment: Unless we treat all ammo as light weapons (two categories smaller), then a Huge arrow (two categories larger than medium) should be treated as a two-handed weapon, and impossible to wield together with a bow. It is still a decent club (nah, its a bad club).

Comment: Wouldn't that only be when used as an improvised melee weapon?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57481/discussion-between-shadowkras-and-royalmurder).

Comment: Is there a published creature that carries specifically sized ammunition  (e.g. "The giant has 20 Large composite bow arrows") or a published trove of specifically sized ammunition (e.g. "If the room is searched, the PCs find 8 *+5 Diminutive light crossbow bolts*")?

Comment: @HeyICanChan reign of winter book 1, has tiny-sized bows. But they do not specifically say the size of the weapon, they simply say "shortbow and arrows (20)" and list the entry as 1d2 damage. The creature is tiny sized and there is no penalty applied to their attack roll.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure monsters are largely assumed to be carrying size-appropriate gear, but my concern is that I'm unaware of—in any official *3.5e* or *Pathfinder* publication—size-specific ammunition, in much the same way that I am unaware of *weapon-specific* ammunition (even though, for example,  shortbow arrows and longbow arrows should probably be incompatible).

Answer (score 2):

**Ammunition are weapons, but damage is based on the size of the bow.**

I believe you could use a larger or smaller arrow than "appropriate", taking the usual penalty for inappropriately sized weapons, which is -2 per size category difference.

Note: the usual reason for using a larger weapon is to get more damage.  But that doesn't work here, because arrows don't have a damage rating; instead, the damage dealt by an archer depends on the size of the *bow*.  Bows are two-handed, so using a larger bow isn't an option usually.  So, an adventurer might use a larger or smaller arrow if they were out of normal ammunition and it was an emergency, but would gain no benefit from doing so.

(Are you trying to get more damage at the expense of accuracy?  Consider the Deadly Aim feat.)

Comment: The intention here would be overcoming a _Wind Wall_ effect, and thereby dealing more damage than having the attack entirely negated.

Comment: For bows and most projectile weapons, yes. But there are all kind of ranged weapons and ammunitions, some have specific damage (http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/ammunition/little-starstones/), others will do damage as one-size different from the weapon (see http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/ammunition/arrow-pronged/)

Comment: @ShadowKras you're right, of course, but since the question only asked about bows and arrows, I didn't feel a discussion of other thrown weapons would be helpful...

Comment: @royalmurder you might get better answers if you edited that into your question: "can an archer use larger arrows in order to overcome a *wind wall* effect?"  I suspect the answer would be "no, even a Large or Huge size arrow would not count as a 'truly massive' projectile which could ignore *wind wall*", but we'd have to see what people said.

Comment: @DanB I'm aiming to find the specific rule, not necessarily how it applies to a particular situation. For that, I think the question is sufficient as is, and whether it applies is best left to a separate question.

Comment: @royalmurder I agree with DanB here. You're on the cusp of an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), trying to make the solution work (*How can I fire big arrows?*) instead of looking for alternative solutions to the problem (*How can an archer defeat a* wind wall *effect?*). I mean, the spell *wind wall* says, "Arrows and bolts are deflected upward and miss," and arguing against *that* is *really* difficult, no matter how big the arrows are! Consider posing a *third* question (I *know*, right?) to address the *real* problem head on.

Comment: @HeyICanChan that was my intention, eventually. I wanted to avoid the mess of the previous question where my query was unclear.

Comment: @royalmurder Fair enough. I look forward to that question. There's more than just *wind wall* that stops archers cold, and there aren't a lot (but there are a few!) good ways to get around them. You might also be interested my answer [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/29079/8610) (although nominally for *Pathfinder*, the same general ideas apply.)